# Android - multiple draw on ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, drawable

I'm new in Android and I have a problem with my app: I have a layout with an ImageView and more EditTexts and Buttons. I'm trying to draw a circle on the Image View every time I input coordinates in a EditText and push a button.
I found a way to make it work the first time, but if I just copy the same code for the 2nd button it draws the new circle and erases the first one. And I want to have both of them...
Somebody can tell me whet I do wrong? Thanks a lot.
My activity:

```
public class IndoorPositioningMainActivity extends Activity {

Button InitialPos = null;
Button P1 = null;

EditText InitialPosX = null;
EditText InitialPosY = null;
EditText InitialPosZ = null;
EditText P1X = null;
EditText P1Y = null;
EditText P1Z = null;

ImageView Image = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_indoor_positioning_main);

    InitialPos = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonInitialPosInput);
    P1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonP1);

    InitialPosX = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.InitialPosInputX);
    InitialPosY = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.InitialPosInputY);
    InitialPosZ = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.InitialPosInputZ);
    P1X = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.P1InputX);
    P1Y = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.P1InputY);
    P1Z = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.P1InputZ);

    Image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    InitialPos.setOnClickListener(InitialPosListener);
    P1.setOnClickListener(P1Listener);

    InitialPosX.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    InitialPosY.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    InitialPosZ.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);    

    P1X.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    P1Y.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    P1Z.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);    


    new PositionAsync().execute();

}

 private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {    
     @Override
     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }                
     @Override
     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {      
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {              
            }
     };

 private OnClickListener InitialPosListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        String x = InitialPosX.getText().toString();
        String z = InitialPosZ.getText().toString();

            float x0 = Float.valueOf(x);
            float z0 = Float.valueOf(z);


        BitmapFactory.Options myOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
     myOptions.inDither = true;
        myOptions.inScaled = false;
        myOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;// important
        myOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.est,myOptions);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);

        Bitmap workingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap);
        Bitmap mutableBitmap = workingBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
        canvas.drawCircle(x0, z0, 50, paint);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);

        }
      };


    private OnClickListener P1Listener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String x11 = P1X.getText().toString();
            String z11 = P1Z.getText().toString();

            float x1 = Float.valueOf(x11);
            float z1 = Float.valueOf(z11);

            BitmapFactory.Options myOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            myOptions.inDither = true;
            myOptions.inScaled = false;
            myOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;// important
            myOptions.inPurgeable = true;

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.est,myOptions);
            Paint paint1 = new Paint();
            paint1.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint1.setColor(Color.BLUE);

            Bitmap workingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap);
            Bitmap mutableBitmap = workingBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
            canvas.drawCircle(x1, z1, 25, paint1);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);

                }
              };

//XML READER
class PositionAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    XMLHelper helper;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        helper = new XMLHelper();
        helper.get();
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    }
}

}
```

my xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10px" >

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="70"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/est" />

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10px" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/InitialPosX"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="X" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/InitialPosInputX"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/InitialPosY"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Y" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/InitialPosInputY"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/InitialPosZ"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Z" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/InitialPosInputZ"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ButtonInitialPosInput"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OK" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/P1X"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="X" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/P1InputX"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/P1Y"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Y" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/P1InputY"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/P1Z"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Z" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/P1InputZ"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ButtonP1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OK" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I suppose that "@drawable/est" is the basic image that will be painted. Then Every time that the button is clicked "est" image is reopened so the previous circles aren't saved.

One possible solution is to use a SurfaceView. There are many tutorials on internet about it.
Other solution is not to load "est" image every time, instead of that try saving the canvas and draw the circles one after another.

Hope it helps

Comment: Finally I've chosen the solution with saving the canvas (it fits the best with the other things I need in my app) - and it works well! thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only draw 1 circle in your `OnClickListener()`, and you draw it on a bitmap that you read from a file every time.

Instead you should save the coordinates into a list, and in the click listener draw all the circles from the list.

Like this:

```
String x11 = P1X.getText().toString();
String z11 = P1Z.getText().toString();

float x1 = Float.valueOf(x11);
float z1 = Float.valueOf(z11);

points.add(new Point(x1, z1));
```

And then:

```
for (Point point : points) {
    canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 25, paint1);
}
```